# Javascript sort array of words ignoring first word

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I have an array of words like the one below:

```
arr = ["id1 abc test", "id#2 XX car house", "id-3 abc home"]
```

I would like to sort it, but ignoring the first word. For example, the output would be:

```
arr = ["id-3 abc home", "id1 abc test", "id#2 XX car house"]
```

Thanks

Comment: What are the sorting rules here ? Please be more clear

Comment: sort lexicographically ignoring the first word. In the example, "id1", "id-3", and "id#2" should not be considerate in the sorting

Comment: So are you considering the unicode code point while sorting ? Still unsure about the rules

Comment: Why `id1 abc test` is before `id-3 abc home`?

Comment: I'm sorry, ```id-3 abc home``` should be before

Comment: `"id#2 XX car house"` stands at beginning because uppercases are before lowercases ("XXX ..." < "abc...").

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 ... does any of the given answers still miss an acceptance criteria?

Answer (score 1):

You can use array.sort where you searchb the index of the space from the string and take for the comparison the original-string just from one position after the space.
**Remark:** For implementing the sort-function you have pay attention that there are 3 different return values for (a,b):

- Return: `< 0` => **a<b**
- Return: `= 0` => **a=b**
- Return: `< 0` => **a>b**

The **result** is now ok after I consider this (I had made here a mistake which is now corrected):
`"id#2 XX car house"`, `"id-3 abc home"`, `"id1 abc test"`
**Note:** XX stands before abc because uppercases are smaller than lowercases e.g. ASCII from "A" is 65 and from "a" is 97.

```js
console.log('A'.charCodeAt(0));
console.log('a'.charCodeAt(0));
```

Here is the code-sample in **extended version** because it's not 100% clearified if for sorting the **upper/lowercase-problematic** is to be considered or not. So I added an extra parameter, so that now both variants are possible:

```js
let arr = ["id1 abc test", "id#2 XX car house", "id-3 abc home"];

function specialSort(ignoreUpperCase) {
    arr.sort( (a,b) => {
        if (ignoreUpperCase) {
            a = a.toUpperCase();
            b = b.toUpperCase()
        }
        a = a.substr(a.indexOf(' ')+1);
        b= b.substr(b.indexOf(' ')+1);
        return (a<b) ? -1 : (a>b) ? 1 : 0;
   });
}

specialSort(true);
console.log('Ignore UpperCases:',arr);

specialSort(false);
console.log('With UpperCases:',arr);
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't sort for the ones that have the same second word. In the example, ```id-3 abc home``` should come before ```id1 abc test```

Comment: @myTest532 myTest532 You are right I made a mistake with the return-values from the sort-function. But you made a mistake for the result, it is: `"id#2 XX car house"`, `"id-3 abc home"`, `"id1 abc test"` because X<a. For explanation look at my answer above.

Comment: @ Peter Seliger The OP wanted to sorted it from beginnig of the second word till the end of string. There stands nothing that he wants to be sorted without uppper/lowercase consideration, so his result is wrong or he had to specify more.

Comment: @ Peter Seliger I edited 20 minutes ago, yes (this was before you sayed something). I didn't do anything wrong with this. Because the OP itself approved it, so it is ok. I can't edit anything here without approving from the OP for this I haven't enough reputation..

Comment: @ Peter Seliger I extended my sorting for both variants, so the OP can decide by himself which one he prefers. I see that you re-editted the question to the last version. That's ok (because the OP approved it) but I would prefer that than there is a hint in the question that uppper/lowercase doesn't matter. But I don't want to start a quarrel about this.

Comment: @Sascha ... OP said ... *"sort lexicographically"*

Comment: @ Peter Seliger You are right OP said this in the comments. I searched for it but I can't find out what this mean with sorting of uppercases.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getStringWithoutFirstWord(str) {
  return str.split(/\s+/).slice(1).join(' ');
}

function compareLoacallyWhilstIgnoringFirstWord(a, b) {
  a = getStringWithoutFirstWord(a); // yes, this is a ...
  b = getStringWithoutFirstWord(b); // ... highly repetitive task.
  return a.localeCompare(b);
}
function compareStronglyAscendingWhilstIgnoringFirstWord(a, b) {
  a = getStringWithoutFirstWord(a);  // yes, this is a ...
  b = getStringWithoutFirstWord(b); // ... highly repetitive task.
  return ((a < b && -1) || (a > b && 1) || 0);
}

const arr = ["id1 abc test", "id#2 XX car house", "id-3 abc home"];


console.log(
  arr.sort(compareLoacallyWhilstIgnoringFirstWord)
);
console.log(
  arr.sort(compareStronglyAscendingWhilstIgnoringFirstWord)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... a working implementation of the already by *Hassan Imam* mentioned [*decorate-sort-undecorate*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63304788/javascript-sort-array-of-words-ignoring-first-word/63305316#63305316) approach ...

```js
function getStringWithoutFirstWord(str) {
  return str.split(/\s+/).slice(1).join(' ');
}

function restoreStringFromDecoratedIgnoredFirstWordData(data) {
  return data.original;
}
function createDecoratedIgnoredFirstWordData(str) {
  return {
    original: str,
    sortable: getStringWithoutFirstWord(str)
  }
}

function compareSortablesLoacally(a, b) {
  return a.sortable.localeCompare(b.sortable);
}
function compareSortablesStronglyAscending(a, b) {
  a = a.sortable;
  b = b.sortable;
  return ((a < b && -1) || (a > b && 1) || 0);
}

const arr = ["id1 abc test", "id#2 XX car house", "id-3 abc home"];


console.log(arr
  .map(createDecoratedIgnoredFirstWordData)
  .sort(compareSortablesLoacally)
  .map(restoreStringFromDecoratedIgnoredFirstWordData)
);

console.log(arr
  .map(createDecoratedIgnoredFirstWordData)
  .sort(compareSortablesStronglyAscending)
  .map(restoreStringFromDecoratedIgnoredFirstWordData)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with regular [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and a small regex that ignores first word:

```js
const arr = ["id1 abc test", "id#2 XX car house", "id-3 abc home"]

const result = arr.sort((a,b) => {

  const [aStr, bStr] = [a,b].map(l => l.replace(/^\S+/g,''));

  return aStr.localeCompare(bStr)

})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do without regex?